# How to install miniconda to Jupyterhub in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, jupyter

I used this [instruction](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/jupyterhub/installation.html) to install Jupyterhub to Kubernetes cluster (chart version 2.0.0). But it doesn't contain Conda (but other images, that is not for k8s, do have it). How can I install miniconda to the kubernetes installation of the Jupyterhub?